# why does comparing three array elements return false

Tags: javascript, jquery

My question might sound silly but it is fundamental. I am trying to compare the elements of an array and I am getting inaccurate result.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   var array =["a","a","a"]
   
   console.log(array[0]===array[1]===array[2])
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

why does it return false? What can I do to get the right result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's break this down...

```
'a'==='a'==='a'
('a'==='a')==='a'
true==='a'
false
```

If you want to compare multiple elements in an array to a specific value, I'd recommend the [`every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) method:

```js
var array = ['a', 'a', 'a'];

console.log(array.every((value) => value === 'a'));
```

Comment: any suggestion how I can compare three elements of array?

Comment: @jason what does Google says?

Answer (score 4):

`array[0]===array[1]` returns true. You then essentially say `true===array[2]`, which is false.

You could say `array[0] === array[1] && array[0] === array[2]` which I think is logically the same.

Comment: any suggestion how I can compare three elements of array?

Answer (score 3):

**Cause of the problem:**

Because:

```
a === b === c
```

is the same as:

```
(a === b) === c
```

thus you are comparing the result of one comparaison (between `a` and `b`) (which will be either `true` or `false`) with the last item `c`.

**Solution:**

To compare the three items use a logical `and` operator like this:

```
a === b && b === c
```

using logical `and` to check if `a` is eqaul to `b` and if `b` is equal to `c` (or if `a` is equal to `c`). If one comparaison fail, then the whole test fail, If not then the three items are equal.

Comment: any suggestion how I can compare three elements of array?

Comment: @jason added the solution.